# Saving HTML of img/image to Disk

Tags: c#, javascript, image, upload, base64

I have a div with an image inside of it. In javascript I am getting the div, and sending the innerHTML of the div to the server. The javascript is oversimplified below:

```
function uploadImage() {       
    var imageInfo = document.getElementById('divImage').innerHTML;
    PageMethods.uploadImage(imageInfo, onSuccess, onError);

} //end function
```

I am currently receiving this on the server as a string.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string uploadImage(string base64FileString){...}
```

The results are as follows:

```
<img height="150" width="150" title="name.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA...../>
```

I need to save this image to disk, and I'm at a loss. It's my understanding that I could get everything past the "base64," (using a split) and create an image using the following:

```
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64FileString);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    image.Save(.....);
```

But this seems very inefficient. Is there a better way to create the image from the string, a better way to receive the string, or better way to pass the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there must be a better way to do this, but I have a solution that at least works. If anyone can point out a more sophisticated way I'm all ears. I would have assumed there was some sort of object that would receive the img on the server to save to disk, but maybe not.

Javascript and webmethod remain unchanged. I passed the InnerHTML of the div to the server, and accept it as a string. On the server I used multiple splits (which I understand to be very slow) to get at the base64 part of the image.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string uploadImage(string base64FileString){

   //Get all of the text right of the comma
    string base64PartTemp= base64FileString.Split(',')[1];

    //The final part of the base64 had a \" to remove
    //Now base64PartFinal is the base64 part of the image only
    string base64PartFinal= base64PartTemp.Split('\"')[0];

    //Get all of the text to the right of the period from original string
    string fileTypePart = base64FileString.Split('.')[1];

    //Because the file is an image the file type will be 3 chars
    string fileType = fileTypePart.Substring(0, 3);

    //Use a new guid for the file name, and append the fileType
    string finalFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "." + fileType;

    //Turn the final base64 part into byte array
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64PartFinal);

    //Get the working directory of the project to store the files
    string path= System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

    //Append that I want to put the image in the images folder, under a designated filename
    path += "Images/" + finalFileName;

    //Write the image to file
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageBytes);

...
}
```

I couldn't find an answer to this for a few days. I hope it helps someone. Like I said, may not be the most efficient solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx):

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64FileString);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageBytes);
```

Absolutely no need to go through `MemoryStream` and the `System.Drawing` namespace once you have the `byte[]`.

Comment: That looks very clean. This would require some sort of split to pull the base64 parts out of the string, correct? Passing the string as itself I'm throwing an exception: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: @ter24 - Well, yes. The `FromBase64String` expects a base64 string only, not the preamble.